# Can I constrain values of variables in sympy (python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy

I am using python 2.7 and sympy. I want to solve an equation, but considering that the values of the variables are constrained (not all values for an integer variable), e.g.,`-25 <= a <= 25`.

How do I do this?

**My code**

```
from sympy import *
from sympy import sin
from sympy.solvers import solve

a, b, c, d = symbols('a b c d')
print solve(cos(a)*sin(b) - sin(a)*cos(b)*cos(d - c), a, b, c, d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can provide a set of equations to the solver, e.g.:

sp.solve([cos(a)*sin(b) - sin(a)*cos(b)*cos(d - c), a + 25], a, b, c, d)

That is, the parameter is iterable.

However, to accomplish what I ultimately need, I have to use an inequality solver.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31226115/python-sympy-inequality-solver-documentation-detailed for a related question I have.